# Angular sets img width to zero

Tags: html, angular, image, angular-template

I want to insert an image in an Angular template, the attribute width is equal to a variable `width` which has the value `null` in some situations.

anyway I want to set `width = ""` in this case (or remove this attribute), but Angular sets the width to zero `width = "0"` which causes the image to be disappeared.

this code:

```
< img src="..." width ="{{ null + ''}}" />
```

is rendered as:

```
<img  src="..." width = "0" />
```

note that the value `null` is came from a variable that is set to `null` dynamically, i.e:

```
this.width = null;

<img src="..." width = "{{width}}" />
```

I don't want to replace the attribute `width` with `style="{width:...}"`, but I may remove this attribute if it has no value.

Comment: Why do you want to set width to ""?

Comment: because in html, this will display the image. but `width="0"` will disappear it.

Comment: So if width = null, you want the image to be visible? What width should it have in that case?

Comment: width is a dynamic value, in some cases it may not be set (i.e equivalent to `null`), it may be a number or a string.

Comment: The img's width attribute is a number, so I would suggest that you try to make sure that your 'width' property is also a number, otherwise it will, as you have experienced, default to a number.

Comment: Ok, so if it is `null`, what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by using `atrr.width` instead of `width`.

```
<!-- this will remove the attribute width -->
<img [attr.width]="null" />

<!-- this will set the attribute width to 250px -->
<img [attr.width]="250" />
```